# Server hacked, 301 redirect, domain lost?

Tags: domain, hacking, 301-redirect

My Ubuntu 16.04 with a new, up to date Wordpress installation (with only one or two Plugins) was hacked. I initiated a new server installation to get rid of anything bad.
It seems like nothing really happened except there was a 301 redirect from my Domain to another one. Now, even after the new server installation, after everything should be completely whiped, my domain is still being redirected to this other domain.

I know 301 means permanent, but is there anyway to get my domain back? Or will it really just like take a few months now? Or stay like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your domain is not lost, but your browser (and those of your users) will cache the redirect, possibly indefinitely.

You can clear your own browser cache yourself, but this won't fix issues your users might have. If this was a new installation that wasn't in use yet, this won't be an issue of course - just clean your own browser cache.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130422/how-long-do-browsers-cache-http-301s